# p5.js not recognizing code in other files

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, processing, p5.js

Working in VSCode on a p5.js project. In one file I create a `blob` class and give it a `createVector` function, then in `sketch.js` I create an instance of `blob` and call `blob.createVector()` in `function setup()`. For some reason it's completely breaking and the console logs:

```
Uncaught (in promise) ReferenceError: createVector is not defined
    at new Blob (blob.js:2)
    at p5.sound.min.js:2
    at Array.map
```

File Structure:

```
|-- blob.js
|-- index.html
|-- jsconfig.json
|-- libraries
|   |-- p5.min.js
|   |-- p5.sound.min.js
|-- sketch.js
|-- style.css
```

sketch.js:

```
var blob;

function setup() {
  blob = new Blob();
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  blob.show();
}
```

blob.js:

```
function Blob() {
  this.pos = createVector(width/2, height/2);
  this.r = 64;

  this.show = function() {
    fill(255);
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r*2, this.r*2);
  }
}
```

index.html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">

    <title>Sketch</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">

    <script src="libraries/p5.min.js"></script>
    <script src="libraries/p5.sound.min.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body>
    <script src="sketch.js"></script>
    <script src="blob.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you create the canvas after you have created the blob, and in the constructor, you are using the widht and height properties wich are inicialised when creating the canvas. That means that the only thing you have to do is to change the order as following:

```
var blob;

function setup() {
  createCanvas(600, 600);
  blob = new Blob();
  
}

function draw() {
  
  background(0);
  blob.show();
}
```

```
class Blob{
  
  constructor(){
    this.pos = createVector(width/2, height/2);
    this.r = 64;
  }

  show(){
    fill(255);
    ellipse(this.pos.x, this.pos.y, this.r*2, this.r*2);
  }
}
```

If you check [this site](https://happycoding.io/tutorials/p5js/creating-classes) you will see that your class constructing approach is a bit outdated. I would try to do it how it is done here.

Answer (score 0):

you have to import the blob.js in the sketch.js

```
import './blob.js';

var blob;

function setup() {
  blob = new Blob();
  createCanvas(600, 600);
}

function draw() {
  background(0);
  blob.show();
}
```